# PHP How to get the name of the clicked link?

Tags: php, html

I have a page that is made up by cards, each card is made up by an image and a title. Some cards call a Javascript funciton and other cards don't, but this is not so important. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CSS/cards.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="./STRUCTURE/IMAGES/logo.png" class="logo_image"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cards">

        <div class="card" name="Drinks">
            <a href="this can be a link to another website" name="Drinks">
                <img src="./STRUCTURE/IMAGES/Drinks.jpg" class="card_image">
                <div class="animated-button">
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <p>Drinks</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="card" name="Coffe">
            <a onclick='thisIsJSfunction("this is an argument")' name="Coffe">
                <img src="./STRUCTURE/IMAGES/Coffe.jpg" class="card_image">
                <div class="animated-button">
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <p>Coffe</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the image and title are contained within an `<a>` tag than can either point to another url or call a Javascript function. BUT, you can also notice that the `<a>` tag has a name="thisIsAname" attribute. What I try to do is when the client clicks on the card, it should call a php function in ANOTHER .php file passing the NAME of the `<a>` tag as an argument(I think a FORM can do it but I'm not sure) and that PHP function from the other .php file will echo back to the original page some html content that will modify some html content inside the div with the `class="cards"`.

I tried my best to be as clear as possible, in case you need more details I can easily edit the post. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't get attributes of the <a> tag after following the link, but you could just modify the link to include a parameter, like `<a href="another.php?name=Coffe">`

Comment: @KarstenKoop ok, I can do that, but I don't need to go to another file, I mean, if I go to another link, will it show a different page?

Comment: @KarstenKoop because what I try to do, is to show the same page but with other cards based on the name of the clicked card before

Comment: You can as well just link to the same page, with a different GET parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get "name" using js, Use ajax to to send post request, example:

```
<body>
  <a href="#"  name="link1" onclick="thisIsJSfunction(this)">test1</a>
  <a href="#"  name="link2" onclick="thisIsJSfunction(this)">test2</a>
  <a href="#"  name="link3" onclick="thisIsJSfunction(this)">test3</a>
  <a href="#"  name="link4" onclick="thisIsJSfunction(this)">test4</a>
<script>
function thisIsJSfunction(e){
    console.log(e['name']);
    let name = e['name'];
}
// ajax
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
url: "ajax-fetch-record.php",
data: { name: name},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(res){
$('#'+name).html(res.name);
}
});
</script>
</body>
```

on PHP side ajax-fetch-record.php

```
<?php
include "config.php"; // db credential and connection
$name = $_POST['name'];
$query="Write your query here";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($data) {
echo json_encode($data); // this will be send to Front (res) success: function(res){
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: ok, but once I do the processing on the php side because the card was clicked, how can I modify the content of the cards class by the echo coming from the php file?

Comment: Move ajax inside js function
we need to change the function slightly
after `success: function(res){` add this line
`e.text=res[0];`
this will change the content of the clicked element with the value that you received from php

Answer (score 1):

use javascript. get attribute "name" use getAttribute and post this value to other php script.

like as

```
function clickLink(){
   const needAttr=this.getAttribute('name')
   ....
   this.preventDefault()
}
```